# Get Json Response when error occured in laravel api

Tags: laravel

I am working with `Laravel` and I want JSON response of error which is thrown by request.

For example, using duplicated email address during signup returns:

```
{
  "email": [
    "The email has already been taken."
  ]
}
```

But I want the response to be like this:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "errors": [ 'errors' ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you validate the request?

Comment: You will need to transform the Errors [message bag](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html) into your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $validator = Validator::make($input);

        if (!$validator->fails()) {
            $responseMessage['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $responseMessage['success'] = false;
            $responseMessage['error'] = $validator->errors();
        }
        return responseMessage;
```

Comment: you can also use.. return Response::json($responseMessage);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using validator then do like this -

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $error = array_flatten($validator->messages()->toArray());
    $response['response'] = [
                "success" => false,
                "error"   => $error
            ]; 

    return $response;
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: no i am not using Validator i am using laravel-jsvalidation, in which validation is written in Request. For my web it is working fine but for app side i want the validation message in json response

Comment: $response['response'] = [  "success" => false,  "error"   => [ 'errors' ]   ];   return Response::json($response);

Answer (score 0):

To return a json error use:

```
$message = 'Self defined error message';
return response()->json([['error' => $message]], 400);
```

400 being the http status code you want to return, could be anything you desire. In this case you would likely want to return 400 (Bad Request).

Output for the code above:

```
[
 {
  "error":"Self defined error message"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$messages = [
        'email.unique'      => $request->email . " has been used",
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->email, [
        'email'     => 'required|max:255|email|unique:users'
        ], $messages);


    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->messages(), 200);
```

Hope this can help you :)